# Having an element on a page clicked on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm working with a Squarespace template and I figured that the easiest way to have a certain behavior occur (basically showing a div that normally stays hidden until a banner is clicked) is to fake a click on the banner itself.

I have two issues here:

1. The particular element cannot be consistently singled out, as the ID seems to change partially every time. So I need to basically get the *first* element of this class that occurs and the anchor tag within.
2. With all the nesting, I'm not sure what exactly needs to be clicked. Is it the div, or the anchor tag, or what?

Here's the code:

```
<div class="item sqs-gallery-design-autocolumns-slide" id="someidthatchanges" data-type="image" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1440px; height: 514px;" overlaydelay="236">
      <a href="thelink" data-dynamic-load="" data-dynamic-receiver="#somestuff" id="idthatchanges">
        <div class="wrapper" id="idthatchanges">
          <div class="project-title" id="idthatchanges">
            <h2 id="idthatchanges">+</h2>
            <h3>— view —</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <img src="someUnimportantImage.gif"/>
     </a>
</div>
```

Here's my unsuccessful jQuery attempt:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
  $('#changingDivID').find('a').trigger('click');
});
```

The above doesn't work in the console either (even when the ID is correct), but doesn't give any errors so it appears to be a targeting issue of some sort.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `.trigger('click')` or jQuery's `.click()` method doesn't actually trigger an anchor's default click behaviour (it just triggers event handlers bound with jQuery and inline click handlers). You can work around that by calling the DOM element's native `.click()` method instead.

Put that together with your note about targetting the first element with the class:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
  $('.sqs-gallery-design-autocolumns-slide:first a')[0].click();
});
```

> *I'm not sure what exactly needs to be clicked. Is it the div, or the anchor tag, or what?*

Well the HTML shown doesn't have any inline event handlers, so we can't tell which element you should target. Except that logically it *should* be the anchor because that is what keyboard-only users can "click".

Comment: That works! But only in the console. I tried having this line in both the header and the footer, and even giving it a delay, but it doesn't seem to work. I suspect it's because of the order of elements loading but I thought that having it in the footer would have solved that issue.

Comment: If the element you're trying to click is created dynamically it may not exist yet. If you give it a *really* long delay and it still doesn't work then I don't know where the element is coming from.

Comment: A 3-second delay works, but this looks a little amateur. Is there some way to run that line of code whenever the entire page is done being loaded rather than giving it a fixed timeout?

Answer (score 0):

maybe what you want is something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".item.sqs-gallery-design-autocolumns-slide").find("a").click();
})
```